# Get column names from first row of SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables first table have field names having below structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FieldNames](
    [SiteId] [int] NULL,
    [Column_1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column_2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column_3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This table contains below data

```
1   FirstName   LastName    City    Coutry
2   City        Coutry      Name    Gender
```

I have another table contains column values having below structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FieldValue](
    [RowId] [int] NULL,
    [SiteId] [int] NULL,
    [Column1_Value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column2_Value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column3_Value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This table contains below data.

```
1   1   ABC     XYZ     Ahmedaad    India
2   1   Hello   Smith   Kodiar  India
3   2   Ahmedaad    India   Happy   data
```

I want the result  something like below for `siteid = 1`

```
**FirstName     LastName     City     Coutry**
ABC             XYZ          Ahmedaad India
Hello           Smith        Kodiar   India
```

Comment: Do you need `**FirstName     LastName     City     Coutry**` to be handled as separate row or do you want this to be interpreted as header of this query?

Comment: this should be as column name only. i do not need it as first row.

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic SQL?

Comment: yes, i know dynamic sql

Comment: Please check my provides statement. It results in 1 SQL statement per SiteId, which then can be executed (dynamic SQL; either in Loop or separateley or whatever...)

Comment: If you think this is a sensible design, you need to seriously question whether an RDBMS is the right tool for implementing the design. You're throwing away everything useful about such databases here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use such design ? It might be flexible but the coding, developemnt, debugging & maintenance will be a nightmare.

```
declare @siteid int = 1
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @sql    = 'SELECT '
        + '[Column1_Value] as ' + quotename([Column_1]) + ', '
        + '[Column2_Value] as ' + quotename([Column_2]) + ', '
        + '[Column3_Value] as ' + quotename([Column_3]) + '  ' + char(13)
        + 'FROM [FieldValue] v' + char(13)
        + 'WHERE v.[SiteId] = @siteid'
from    [FieldNames] n
where   n.SiteId    = @siteid

print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql, N'@siteid int', @siteid
```

Comment: Nice idea with quotename. Anyways, in my example I used the FieldValue table as leading table in order to NOT execute a query where I do not have any values. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT [FirstName],
        [LastName],
        [City],
        [Coutry]
FROM [FieldNames] n
INNER JOIN [dbo].[FieldValue] v
    ON n.[SiteId]=v.[SiteId]
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES  (   v.Column1_Value,
                          v.Column2_Value,
                          v.Column3_Value,
                          v.name)
            )
dt ([FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Coutry])
WHERE n.[SiteId]=1
```

Result

```
FirstName   LastName    City        Coutry
------------------------------------------
ABC          XYZ        Ahmedaad    India
Hello        Smith      Kodiar      India
```

Comment: it does not work because "[FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Coutry]" is not by static column names.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create the corresponding (dynamic) queries via another SQL query and execute these in a loop (or separately if required). The following query will provide you with the dynamic statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fv.[SiteId],
'SELECT     fv.RowId, ' +
'fv.SiteId, ' +
'fv.Column1_Value AS ' + fn.Column_1 + ', ' +
'fv.Column2_Value AS ' + fn.Column_2 + ', ' +
'fv.Column3_Value AS ' + fn.Column_3 + ', ' +
'fv.Name ' +
'FROM [dbo].[FieldValue] fv ' +
'WHERE fv.SiteId = ' + CAST(fv.[SiteId] AS varchar(10)) AS stmt

FROM [dbo].[FieldValue] fv
JOIN [dbo].[FieldNames] fn ON fv.SiteId = fn.SiteId
```